# Scrapy: crawled and scraped 0 items

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm trying to get companies' info from government website and using Scrapy for it.My spider code is the following one.

#### Spider code

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from ..items import CompaniesHouseItem

class SpendolaterSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spendolater'
    allowed_domains = ['beta.companieshouse.gov.uk']
    start_url = ['https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/10511127']

    custom_settings = {"DOWNLOAD_DELAY": 1,}

    def crawling(self, response):
        domain = "https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/"
        for url in response.css("a::attr('href')").extract():
            if not url.startswith('https://'):
                continue 
            if domain not in url:
                yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        for contents in response.xpath('//*[@id="page-container"]'):
            item = CompaniesHouseItem()
            item["name"] = response.xpath('//*[@id="company-name"]').extract()
            item["location"] = response.xpath('//*[@id="content-container"]/dl/dd').extract()
            item['foundation'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="company-creation-date"]').extract()
            items['type'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="company-type"]').extract()
            items['SIC'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="sic0"]').extract()
            yield item
```

It doesn't show any error when running but doesn't extract any info.
"Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)" message is shown in command line after running.

"items.py" file is as follows

#### items.py

```
import scrapy

class CompaniesHouseItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    location = scrapy.Field()
    foundation = scrapy.Field()
    type = scrapy.Field()
    SIC = scrapy.Field()
```

Output is as follows.

#### Output

```
2018-03-14 17:51:56 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.0 started (bot: companies_house)
2018-03-14 17:51:56 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.1.1.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.4.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 17.9.0, Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)], pyOpenSSL 17.5.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017), cryptography 2.1.4, Platform Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
2018-03-14 17:51:56 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'companies_house', 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1, 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'companies_house.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['companies_house.spiders']}
2018-03-14 17:51:57 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2018-03-14 17:51:57 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2018-03-14 17:51:57 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2018-03-14 17:51:57 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2018-03-14 17:51:57 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-03-14 17:51:57 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-03-14 17:51:57 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-03-14 17:51:57 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-03-14 17:51:57 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 14, 8, 51, 57, 239817),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 14, 8, 51, 57, 231826)}
2018-03-14 17:51:57 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Any advice would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have `def start_requets(self)` but `start_url` so Scrapy will scrape URLs from list `start_url` and use your callback method `parse`.

I mean, you are missing `def parse(self, response)` change `def crawling(self, response)` to `def parse(self, response)`

Also your code's logic is completely wrong, just think of code's flow before writing it.

Put the page in `start_url`  which has company links, listing page i mean

Then create `def parse(self, response)` and create a for loop to iterate over each company link.

Comment: Thanks, I reviewed logic and added `def start_requests(self)` function, also revised `def parse(self, response)` function as advised. 
Now it works well. Your advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @SY9 If that solved your problem can you accept my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Because Scrapy, by default, read the first addresses to scrape in `start_urls` (not `start_url`) and start parsing with `parse` method (not `crawling`). Try a rename operation and relaunch your spider.

Comment: Thanks. I renamed those functions and now it works well.
I appreciate your advice.